# Multiple Servers with identical services

Tags: wcf, web-services, proxies, service-reference

I have a dozen servers in different locations all running the same web service application but each going against their own SQL Server DB. I am writing a desktop application that consumes the web services. I want to present the user with a drop down of all servers in the network that are running the same wweb service application. Do I have to add a ServiceReference for each of the servers running the web service app and thereby having as many proxies as there are servers? Or can a define a single instance of the services and dynamically build a list of endpoints to select from a drop down?

Answer (score 2):

If they are all using the same webservice code, just add one reference, then swap out the URL on the proxy before making calls with the proper endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Mitchel, that was my approach as well. Was just wanting to see if there were other approaches.